# My Sites default Pages library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, library

I am wondering if it is possible to turn on the default 'Pages' library for the My Sites Host Collection.  I am currently the My Site Host Collection administrator with Design and Full Control.  I know this because when browsing My Site's 'About Me' page, when I click on my name on the Ribbon I can see the 'Personalise this Page' and when I click on the cog I can see 'Edit Page', 'Add a Page', 'Design Manager' etc.

So I continue to 'Add a Page', give it a name, and click OK.  The page gets created and I get re-directed to it, ready to edit it.  However if I then navigate away from this page, there is no way for me to navigate back to it because no default 'Pages' library exists when I click on 'Site Contents'.

How can I enable this library so I may provision a new page that everyone will have access to from their My Site, which they will then be able to personalise.

I have tried turning on various features via 'Site Collection Features' and 'Manage Site Features' from 'Site Settings' with no luck.  The only additions are a greater selection of web parts I'm able to put on a page.

I have activated in both of the above options:
'SharePoint Server Standard Site Features'
'SharePoint Server Publishing'
'SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Features'

Comment: Have you tried enabling Publishing Feature?

Comment: Hi Amal, I have activated 'SharePoint Server Standard Site Features', 'SharePoint Server Publishing', 'SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Features' within 'Manage Site Features'.  I have activated the same for 'Site Collection Features'.